# Convert timestamp in sas

Tags: sql, sas

I'm trying to import a timestamp variable from sql to sas. The variable looks like "2014-05-02 23:40:42". If I use proc import, it automatically gets converted to $25.

I hope to convert this timestamp into a date variable so I could analyze the recency. However, I couldn't successfully do it using format:

format created DATETIME19.;

(This returns an error message: ERROR 48-59: The format $DATETIME was not found or could not be loaded.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try the `anydtdtm.` informat:

```
data _null_;
  x="2014-05-02 23:40:42";
  y=input(x,anydtdtm25.);
  put y= datetime25.;
run;
```

gives:

```
y=02MAY2014:23:40:42
```